# Kendo DropdownList Selected Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

For some reason I have really struggled with the Kendo DropdownList. I can't seem to figure out how to get the selected item from my controller's post action. Here is a simple example of code I have.

Model:

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
    public DemoViewModel()
    {
        SelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel = new DemoViewModel();
        var oneItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1", Selected = false };
        ViewModel.SelectList.Add(oneItem);
        oneItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2", Selected = false };
        ViewModel.SelectList.Add(oneItem);
        oneItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3", Selected = false };
        ViewModel.SelectList.Add(oneItem);
        oneItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Item 4", Selected = false };
        ViewModel.SelectList.Add(oneItem);


        ViewModel.SelectedID = "3";
        return View(ViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DemoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //Do something with the updated viewmodel
    }
```

View Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ProductsList")
    .BindTo(Model.SelectList)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Value(Model.SelectedID)
)
```

now when my post action is executed, I get a DataViewModel parameter value passed in but the SelectList property is empty and I have no idea which item in the list was selected by the user. I expected the DataViewModel that was passed to my post action would look exactly like the one passed to the view with the exception of what changed. I.e. I expected the SelectList to contain the same 4 items that was passed to the view plus the "Selected" property set to true for the one that was actually selected. Now I know my assumptions were wrong. So, my question is, how do I pass a Model to my view that contains a list of items, display that list in a kendo dropdownlist, and know which item was selected once the post action is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given your dropdownlist the name `ProductsList` but you model does not contain a property with that name. Change it to `SelectedID` so it matches the property you want to bind to.

Note it is recommend you use the strongly typed version

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedID) ....
```

Now when you submit, the value of `viewModel.SelectedID` will be the value of the selection option.

Side note: There is no point setting the `Selected = false` property of `SelectListItem` (its `false` by default), but in any case its ignored when you strongly bind to a model property. Your 3rd option will be selected when you first render the view because `SelectedID = 3;` and you have a option with `value="3"`.

Note also the `SelectList` property will be empty because you do not generate controls for each `SelectListItem` in the view (nor should you). Ensure that if you return the view that you repopulate the collection.